# PinInputField value not changing color when color changes

Tags: reactjs, chakra-ui

So this is code for a two-factor authentication input field. the color is conditional depending on

```
  const color = Store.get('theme') == 'dark' ? dark.color.input.color : light.color.input.color
```

The problem is, when the color changes, the value in the input field that's type doesnt change, unless you type another value.

```
<PinInput
              otp
              size="lg"
              placeholder=""
              focusBorderColor="#a5a505"
              autoFocus
              manageFocus
              onComplete={handleComplete}
            >
              <PinInputField mr="15px" color={color} />
              <PinInputField mr="15px" color={color} />
              <PinInputField mr="15px" color={color} />
              <PinInputField mr="15px" color={color} />
              <PinInputField mr="15px" color={color} />
              <PinInputField mr="15px" color={color} />
            </PinInput>
```

Is there a way to make the values change color automatically when color changes?

Comment: You're trying to change the color with the color mode?

Comment: @AndrewGillis not sure what you mean by that. there is a toggle on the page that sets color to light and dark